# Problems casting in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having problems CASTing in a foreach loop.

I have the following code that consists of a basic object:

```
public class DBFieldMap
{
    public String fieldName { get; set; }
    public String fieldValue { get; set; }
    public DBFieldMap() { }
    public DBFieldMap(String fname, String fvalue)
    {
        fieldName = fname;
        fieldValue = fvalue;
    }
}
```

A Dictionary using the above object

```
public class MappedSQLFields : Dictionary<String, DBFieldMap>
{
    public MappedSQLFields() 
    {
        this.Add("firstname", new DBFieldMap());
        this.Add("lastname", new DBFieldMap());
        this.Add("email", new DBFieldMap());
        etc...

    }
}
```

Another object with a property that is based on the above object

```
public class Audience : IEnumerable
{
...
        public MappedSQLFields audienceSQLMap
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

I would like to be able to loop through the audienceSQLMap property and extract the values for the fieldName and fieldValue properties of the DBFieldMap Dictionary object but I'm receiving the following error though at the "foreach" line.  I've tried various explicit casts but still can't seem to be able to get the CASTing to work.

```
foreach (MappedSQLFields item in audience.audienceSQLMap)
{
    //Do something with item.fieldName and item.fieldValue
}
```

> Error 49  Cannot convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair' to
>   'MappedSQLFields'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

**The SAGA Continues**

Okay, now that the above works thanks to everyone's help below, now I'm having problems casting the JSON equivalent of the object back to the original object.  I'm receiving the same error I originally was receiving, but have tried the various CAST statements I can think of and it's still gives me grief.  I'm obviously missing something regarding this whole topic.

This works fine:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(audienceSQLMap);
```

Error on this line:

```
this.audienceSQLMap = (MappedSQLFields)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(json,typeof(KeyValuePair<String, DBFieldMap>));
```

Comment: From your code it appears that `audience.audienceSQLMap` is a single instance of `MappedSQLFields` so you can't iterate over it. Can you better clarify the `Audience` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It expects you to be iterating over a key/value pair.

Modify your code to use a `KeyValuePair<string, DBFieldMap>`:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DBFieldMap> item in audience.audienceSQLMap)
```

Or, more succinctly, just use `var`:

```
foreach (var item in audience.audienceSQLMap)
{
    //Do something with item.fieldName and item.fieldValue
    var name = item.Value.fieldName;
    var value = item.Value.fieldValue;
    ...
}
```

If all you need is the values of the Dictionary though, you could just iterate over those:

```
foreach (DBFieldMap map in a.audienceSQLMap.Values)
{
    var name = map.fieldName;
    var value = map.fieldValue;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much.  That definitely solved the problem and I espeically appreciate your suggestion to just iterate over the Dictionary - that was my ultimate goal!  But, I'm curious to understand, why I needed to iterate over the KeyValuePair<> as opposed to the Dictionary object.  Aren't they the same thing?  Thanks.

Comment: Okay.  Now I think I understand.  _There aren't multiple MappedSQLFields to iterate over.._ helps.  I'm going to have to chew on this a few times before it becomes natural.

Comment: @GranWinney - Thanks.  I tried that just now.  Deserialize() returns an object but the message trying your suggestion is that it doesn't contain a method ToDictionary.  I was simply trying to reverse _var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(audienceSQLMap);_  I thought that should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Error:  MappedSQLFields doesn't contain a constructor for one parameter.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The key parts of the code you posted are:

```
public class DBFieldMap
{
    public String fieldName { get; set; }
    public String fieldValue { get; set; }
    // elided
}

public class MappedSQLFields : Dictionary<String, DBFieldMap> { ... }

public class Audience
{
    public MappedSQLFields audienceSQLMap { get; set; }
}
```

but want to iterate over the items in `audience.audienceSQLMap` (where I assume `audience` is an instance of `Audience`).

You can take advantage of the fact that `audience.audienceSQLMap` is `MappedSQLFields`, which is [`Dictionary<String, DBFieldMap>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is in turn a collection of [`KeyValuePair<String, DBFieldMap>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The thing to do here is:

```
foreach ( IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<<String, DBFieldMap>> kvp in audience.audienceSQLMap )
{
    DBFieldMap map = kvp.Value;
    //Do something with map.fieldName and map.fieldValue
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to helping solve this.  Though I ended up using Grant's solution, your code and explanation was very helpful.